# WARP implies completeness, transitivity and thus rationalizability. What is wrong with the statement?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, utility, supply-and-demand, preferences

Let $A$ be a menu and $R$ be a complete and transitive binary relation. Define choice correspondence generated by $R$:

$$c_R(A)=\{x\in A|| xRy \ \forall y\in A\}.$$

Theorem (from Kreps 1988): for any correspondence $c$, the following conditions are equivalent:

1. $c$ satisfies WARP
2. There exists a transitive and complete $R$ such that $c=c_R$.

Given $A$ is finite and $c=c_R$, it is obvious that $c$ can be represent by a utility function. Then why do we need SARP/GARP to rationalize a choice correspondence with a utility function? What was wrong with my logics?

Comment: Is Kreps (1988) the book titled *Notes on the Theory of Choice*? I don't think the book mentions WARP as such. Can you give a precise statement of the theorem in Kreps (1988)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Notes on the Theory of Choice* (assuming this is what you refer to by "Kreps (1988)"), Kreps does not appear to mention WARP as such. But he does refer to "Houthakker's axiom" (Houthakker 1950, *Economica*), which is actually SARP, not WARP.

Your conditions 1 and 2 are equivalent if there are only two goods. If there are more than two goods, WARP in condition 1 must be replaced by SARP to preserve the equivalence. Jehle and Reny (2011) have an intuitive explanation for this:

> [W]ith two goods, the pairwise ranking of bundles implied through revealed preference turns out to have no intransitive cycles. [...] And when this is so, there will be a utility representation generating the choice function.

SARP basically posits conditions that explicitly rule out intransitive cycles in revealed preferences with a general $n$-good environment.

WARP/SARP differ from GARP in that the former presumes the availability of infinitely many choice data to build a choice *function* with, whereas GARP only requires a finite set of choice data.